# Check if a character is in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I'm looking for a simple way to check if values in an R data frame have comma (or any character for that matter).

Let's suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("apple","orange", "banana","strawberries"), 
                 B = c(23,12,10,15), 
                 C = c("2,53", "1.35","0,25","1,44"))
```

If I know the column with commas in it I use this:

```
which(grepl(",",df$C))
length(which(grepl(",",df$C)))
```

However, I want an output as the one above but not specifying the column of my dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simply go through all three columns; `sapply` works here:

```
sapply(df, grep, pattern = ",")


##output:

# $A
# integer(0)
# 
# $B
# integer(0)
# 
# $C
# [1] 1 3 4
```

To get the `length` you can do this:

```r
sapply(sapply(df, grep, pattern = ","), length)

# A B C D 
# 0 0 3 0
```

Comment: You can apply `length` on the output and get the ***answer*** which is `3`.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat simpler to grasp solution; first, convert your data frame to vector.

```
df2vector <- as.vector(t(df))

df2vector 
# [1] "apple"        "23"           "2,53"         "orange"       "12"          
# [6] "1.35"         "banana"       "10"           "0,25"         "strawberries"
# [11] "15"           "1,44"
```

Then use your approach.

```
length(which(grepl(",",df2vector)))
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Neat solution. The one-liner can be (obviously) `length(which(grepl(",",as.vector(t(df)))))`. Please avoid including `>` and `+` in your code so users can easily copy/paste them and hit run! Moreover, it's a good practice to add `#` in front of results, because they are not run-able and, again, we want to copy, paste, and run. Cheers. +1